# how to refer 3rd party dll's to silverlight application?

Tags: dll, silverlight-4.0, reference

I am new to silverlight. I have a silverlight application and i need to refer some 3rd party dll's for some functionality. If i try to add reference for few dll's i get the below error:

You cant add reference as the dll was not built against silverlight runtime.Silverlight projects will work with silverlight only.

For few dll's i get the error below:

A reference to dll cannot be added. Please make sure that the file is accessible, and that it has a valid assembly or COM component.

How do i solve this?

Answer (score 1):

Silverlight has it's own target in .NET. As such, any assemblies a Silverlight application references has to be built with the Silverlight target. Ask the vendor if they have a Silverlight build.

Comment: is there no workaround? like adding another project, and referring that class in my silverlight application?

Comment: @user869861 There is no work around. If it happens to be something you can use on the back-end in a service, you can use something like WCF to communicate with a back-end server that uses your assembly.